# how to add callback with param in this condition?

Tags: javascript, callback

i have one table dom element

```
<table id='acc001'>...</table>
```

and i create one popup menu to get tr data after clicking on that tr element

```
  var tr = $('<tr>').appendTo('#acc001');
  popupMenu.draw_menu(tr);

  var popupMenu = {
    menu : [
      {'string':'add data','type':'input','callback':function(tr){console.log(tr);}},
      {'string':'edit data','type':'input','callback':function(tr){console.log(tr);}}
    ],
    draw_menu : function(tr){
        for(i in this.menu)
        {
          var div = $('<div>',{'text':this.menu[i].string}).appendTo('#infoDiv');
          $(div).bind('click',this.menu[i].callback); // i cannot send param for this callback
        }
    }
  }
```

the problem is after create the menu but i cannot get tr content after clicking them.
all console.log cannot show that ..

1. so how to add and send param for this callback?
2. any other way to do this code properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in a function and pass `tr` to the callback:

```
$(div).bind('click',(function(callback) {
    return function() { callback(tr) }
})(this.menu[i].callback));
```

(Edited: `this` would not be from proper context inside the event handler; fixed again)

Comment: Note that `this` in the callback is the clicked `div`. You should save the the context with a closure.

Comment: Yep, just caught myself a second ago :)

Comment: @misterjack: what does it means?

Comment: @lanzz : all menu run second callback

Comment: Whoops, I'm not very attentive today.

Comment: @lanzz : how it do this perfectly? what type of function is this?
why it's form like (function).(function)? can you give me any clue/keyword to learn this?

Comment: The outer function establishes a closure, the only purpose of which is to hold a reference to `this.menu[i].callback` for the inner function to access.